# jsTree Open a branch

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, jstree

I am using the JQuery plugin jsTree, http://www.jstree.com/
I am able to expand the whole tree with the following method:

```
$("#tree").jstree("open_all");
```

and also a specific node:

```
$("#tree").jstree("open_node", $('#childNode'));
```

I am having difficulty opening a branch of the tree, open branch opens it fine but does not open its parent if it has one.

Has anyone successully done this with jsTree?  Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks

Eef

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the binding

```
$("#tree").bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) { 
  if((data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj)).length) { 
    data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj).open_node(this, false); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: shouldn't there be some kind of 'unbind' in the end?

Comment: @NirO. for what reason?

Answer (score 20):

Your code for open branch is correct.

For example. Source of tree:

```
    <div id="treeTask">
       <ul>
          <li id="node_37"><a href="#">TEST1</a>
              <ul>
                  <li id="node_38"><a href="#">TEST2</a></li>
                  <li id="node_39"><a href="#">TEST3</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Open node:

```
$("#treeTask").jstree("open_node", $("#node_38"));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ! :D

Comment: This works because you defined nodes in HTML, so they all are loaded and DOM is constructed at the moment you call open_node. This is unfortunately not the case if you use JSON data to build the tree.

Answer (score 10):

Try this code to open node till nth Level

```
$("#myTree").jstree({options}).bind('loaded.jstree', function (e, data) {
    /** 
     * Open nodes on load (until x'th level) 
     */
    var depth = 3;
    data.inst.get_container().find('li').each(function (i) {
        if (data.inst.get_path($(this)).length <= depth) {
            data.inst.open_node($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: A really nice solution.

Comment: Better late than never! :-D @martincarlin87

Comment: can you please tell me what to pass in options variable ?? please ??

Comment: TypeError: data.inst is undefined

Comment: @JavascriptCoder It is now renamed to data.instance

Comment: How could we implement similar logic in a button click handler (instead of binding to loaded.jstree event)  ?  Has anyone created a button and been able to have it open jstree to a particular level/depth, without binding it to jstree api events?  Im not sure how i get data.inst.get_container() outside of the jstree api event (inside my button click handler) 
  <button id="openToLevel3"> Open to Level 3</button>

Answer (score 5):

Here is function that can open a specific node and all its parents.

```
function expandNode(nodeID) {
    // Expand all nodes up to the root (the id of the root returns as '#')
    while (nodeID != '#') {
        // Open this node
        $("#jstree").jstree("open_node", nodeID)
        // Get the jstree object for this node
        var thisNode = $("#jstree").jstree("get_node", nodeID);
        // Get the id of the parent of this node
        nodeID = $("#jstree").jstree("get_parent", thisNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: only one that would work for me. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 3):

i found Ted's code working, but had to change it a bit:

```
 $('#jsTree').bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) { 
      if((data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj)).length) { 
        data.inst.open_node(data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj), false,true); 
      } 
    });
```

Comment: I was Ted back in the day :)

Answer (score 3):

just use this if you use json

```
$("#treeId").on
('loaded.jstree', function() {
 $("#treeId").jstree("open_node", $("#nodeId"));
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

None of previous worked for me, so I have created this code, and it works like a charm :)

```
$('#tree').on('open_node.jstree', function (event, data) { 
    if(data.node.parent !== "#") { 
        data.instance.open_node(data.node.parent); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Expand pasted, dragged and dropped node for jstree 3.3.1
        var objtree = $('#jstree');
        objtree.bind('paste.jstree', function(e, d) { objtree.jstree('open_all', '#' + d.parent); });
        $(document).bind('dnd_move.vakata', function(e, d) { objtree.jstree('open_all', $(d.event.target).closest('.jstree-node').attr('id')); });
        $(document).bind('dnd_stop.vakata', function(e, d) { objtree.jstree('open_all', $(d.event.target).closest('.jstree-node').attr('id')); });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add more details to your answer and explain why that is the 'correct' way to do it